# What is "Equal3~1" and "Selector0~2" in my Data Path?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, quartus

I trying to analysis a critical path in my SystemVerilog design using Quartus Prime. In the timing report, under the Data Path section, I can see the path details as it goes through my design.

Certain values of the path say "...|Equal3~1|datac" and "...|Equal3~1|combout", etc. Then there are some that are "...|Selector0~2|datac", etc.

[image: Quartus Timing Report]

And here is the specific things I am referring to:

[image: Weird notation of signals]

There are many such 'keywords' that I am seeing (Equal, Selector, LessThan2). But I can't seem to figure our what these signals are in my design. I assume they are the name given to some Mux or "==" operator in my SystemVerilog HDL, but how can I figure out exactly what these are referring to?

I am new to this notation and so maybe my question is a bit vague, but I would appreciate any help!

Comment: this looks like a generated name created by the tool. It just needed to generate a few copies of Selector102 (~0 and ~1), and so on. You should match it to your code to understand why it does that.

Comment: I see, so the `~<number>` is just the copy number of that generated name? Also, how would I go about finding what that generated name references in my actual HDL code?

Comment: You might be able to right click on the funny names and select "cross probe to code" or "cross probe to schematic" or something else that informs you where in the design that path is located.